# Neo4j in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, neo4j

I am a beginner in  `Neo4j`. I need to load a `.csv` file and apply the `Louvain` algorithm to the dataset in the `NetBeans`. I added `graph-algorithms-algo-3.3.0.0.jar` in my project library. Should I add other files? What code do i need to load this file?please help me. Thankful.